# getting the wrong answer while converting a number n in base b (2<=b<=10) to a decimal number:

Tags: python, binary

I've created a function to convert number n to any base b, for ex: `4325` stands for 
`5 + 2 x 10 + 3 x 10 x 10 + 4 x 10 x 10 x 10

and I've tried to use this logic for conversion but it's returning the wrong answer.

```
def decimal(n,b):
    result=0
    multiplier=1
    while n>0:
        result+=n%b *multiplier
        multiplier=b
        n/=b
    return result
```

Comment: Can you provide examples of what you expect this to do, what it does instead, and where is the *first* place in the function's execution that it misbehaves?

Comment: for example, we want to convert 63 to base 4 which is 333, but it is showing the wrong answer 13.49, I think the function is misbehaving at line 5

Comment: You miss in your logic that the result shall be a base 10 number, that shall _look_ like a base 4 (or whatever base) number. You probably want to create a string, not a number - that would also work for base > 10.

Comment: yah, I know the logic to convert when the base is greater than 10 but this logic is just for base < 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you don't clearly understand how numeral system works. Here's corrected version of your code:

```
def decimal(n, b):
    result = ""
    while n > 0:
        result = str(n % b) + result
        n = n // b
    return result
```

**Numeral system is just a representation of number.** Changing system doesn't affects on value of variable.

So I'll list few mistakes you've made in your code:

1. *Return value type.* As I mentioned before, we should return representation of number, so you can't handle a representation as another number. It's possible, but it ruins the logic. I would recommend you to proceed with `str`;
2. *Loop condition.* In your code you use regular division by `10`, which is completely break a logic of function, cause normally it should be divided by numeral system base (value of variable `b`). But that's not the only problem. Return of `n / 10` will be `float` value, which theoretically will never be equal `0`. The only reason, why your loop stopped is the way how python works with floats (after some number of iterations `n` will be rounded to `0.0`).

Comment: i've just edited the wright code,actually previous one was to convert from a decimal number n to a number in base b (2 <=b<=10) and this one is to converts a number n in base b (2<=b<=10) to a decimal number.

Comment: @HarshYadav, sorry, I don't understand. What code are you speaking about?

Comment: actually, in previous code, I was reducing the original number by the base b n/=b itself, but in this code, I'm reducing the number by 10 n/=10

Comment: @HarshYadavm why?

Comment: thank you so much @OlvinRoght, my problem is solved. actually, I got frustrated when my code wasn't working  and get confused